# math captcha giving wrong value

Tags: php, html

The following match captcah form is not giving correct. The output is coming as ***"Captcha is incorrect!"*** in both the cases of correct value as well as in correct values entered. I have tried but unable to find the solution. The souces codes are given below:

**FORM.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<form action="check.php" method="post">';
$rand_int1 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
$rand_int2 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
$cap_ans = $rand_int1 + $rand_int2;
$_SESSION['cap_ans'] = $cap_ans;
echo 'What is '.$rand_int1.' + '.$rand_int2.' ?<br>
<input type="text" name="cap_inp">
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>';
?>
```

**CHECK.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
$cap_inp = $_POST['cap_inp'];
$cap_ans = $_SESSION['cap_ans'];

if($cap_inp != $cap_ans) {
    echo 'Captcha is incorrect!';
}
else {
    echo 'Captcha is correct, congratulations! :)';
}
?>
```

Can any body help me / suggest the correct code please?

Comment: `var_dump($cap_inp, $cap_ans);`

Comment: where it to be incorporated - i.e FORM.PHP or CHECK.PHP

Comment: @user3410277 in form.php. It will help you debug the values submitted and saved in the session.

Comment: Do you have `$cap_inp` variable in form.php?

Comment: when i entered 2=3 =? as 5. the output coming as-   string(1) "5" NULL Captcha is incorrect!

Comment: not working .  php: 5.3.6

Comment: Add `print_r($_SESSION);` in your check.php, seems like your session has not been set.

Comment: Dear Mr. Lenny, still its i not working. Could you help me correcting the complete code of CHECk.PHP

Comment: You need to show the output of the print_r, what did it return?

Comment: with following adds in CHECK.PHP: var_dump($cap_inp, $cap_ans); print_r($_SESSION); the math: 1=4 = ? the out put: **string(1) "5" NULL Captcha is incorrect!Array ( )**

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and Works well. Problem must be somewhere else, in code you didn't post.

```
if(!empty($_POST['cap_inp'])){
    $cap_inp = $_POST['cap_inp'];
    $cap_ans = $_SESSION['cap_ans'];

    if($cap_inp != $cap_ans) {
            echo 'Captcha is incorrect!';
    }
    else {
            echo 'Captcha is correct, congratulations! :)';
    }
} else {
    $rand_int1 = substr(mt_rand(), 0, 1);
    $rand_int2 = substr(mt_rand(), 0, 1);

    $cap_ans = $rand_int1 + $rand_int2;

    $_SESSION['cap_ans'] = $cap_ans;
    echo '
        <form method="post">
            What is '.$rand_int1.' + '.$rand_int2.'?<br>
            <input type="text" name="cap_inp">
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
    ';
}
```

Returned

> Captcha is correct, congratulations! :)

Comment: This is server scripting language, not working on your server. Try to run my code at blank page.

Comment: checked in a blank page of yahoo business but not working. I have tried in Google Chrome; Explore, Firefox. None of them giving correct output.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Is there some errors? Chceck by `error_reporting(E_ALL);`